# Salesforce/SOQL: How to retrieve all column names from Account?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to retrieve all the column names from Salesforce by SOQL Query that I get via Pentaho as well with the following code

```
select QualifiedApiName
from FieldDefinition 
where EntityDefinition.DeveloperName='Account'
```

Pentaho lists 65 fields, the query only 50.
The following fields are missing (list contains 16 instead of 15 fields for some reason)

```
BillingStreet
BillingCity
BillingState
BillingPostalCode
BillingCountry
BillingLatitude
BillingLongitude
BillingGeocodeAccuracy
ShippingStreet
ShippingCity
ShippingState
ShippingPostalCode
ShippingCountry
ShippingLatitude
ShippingLongitude
ShippingGeocodeAccuracy
```

Would you mind telling me the SOQL code I need in order the get all the 65 fields? Would appreciate that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields you've listed are components of compound fields, specifically the `ShippingAddress` and `BillingAddress` compound Address fields.

What you want is most likely to write your query against [`EntityParticle`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entityparticle.htm) in the Tooling API, which should give you parity. But fundamentally it's important to know that neither list is wrong - your query and Pentaho are just using APIs that have slightly different definitions of what a field is, in the complicated situation around compound fields.

You could also write REST API calls against the Describe API, if you're not limited to using just SOQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
The following did the trick
`SELECT Name FROM EntityParticle WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName ='Account'`

Answer (score 6):

Go to Developer Console,
Open **Account** Object

[image]

New window will open, select all the fields(Ctrl A or drag)
and click on Query
Below window will have all the fields queried

[image]